# how to find no of categorical columns and numerical columns in dataset

Tags: python, pandas

I need to find number of numerical and categorical columns

Check how many categorical and numerical columns are there

Categorical - object type

Numerical - int,float

Boolean - bool

```
df = pd.read_csv("titanic.csv")
```

as i can only get name of the columns with `df._get_numeric_data().columns` 
i need sum of the columns

Comment: What about `df.dtypes.value_counts()` to tell you specifically how many of each dtype there are? Or use [select_dtypes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) with `'number'` to select all numeric regardless of, for example, `float` vs `int`

Answer (score 4):

You can use `columns = df.applymap(np.isreal).all()`, Output will be,

```
PassengerId     True
Pclass          True
Name           False
Sex            False
Age             True
SibSp           True
Parch           True
Ticket         False
Fare            True
Cabin          False
Embarked       False
dtype: bool
```

All columns with numarical values will return `true`, othervice return `false`.

Also, you can get the true and false count using

`print((columns).value_counts())`

Output :

```
True     6
False    5
dtype: int64
```

Which means is df has 6 numerical and  5 categorical columns.

Answer (score 1):

First check `dtype` per column:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'float': [1.0],
                   'int': [1],
                   'datetime': [pd.Timestamp('20180310')],
                   'string': ['foo'],
                   'float2': [1.0]
                  })
df.dtypes
```

```
float              float64
int                  int64
datetime    datetime64[ns]
string              object
float2             float64
dtype: object
```

Then count how many of each type you have:

```
df.dtypes.value_counts()
```

```
float64           2
datetime64[ns]    1
object            1
int64             1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: This really helped 

Comment: Cool! @venkat0107 is your question answered then?

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2],
                   'b': [True, False],
                   'c': [1.0, 2.0],
                   'd': ['play', 'draw']})
```

You can use
`df.dtypes.value_counts()` to get the total number of specific datatypes.

Output:

```
int64      1
bool       1
float64    1
object     1
dtype: int64
```

To get all numeric columns:
`df.select_dtypes(include='number')`

Output:

```
    a   c
0   1   1.0
1   2   2.0
```

To get all categorical columns:
`df.select_dtypes(include='object')`

Output:

```
    d
0   play
1   draw
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
## from https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_stack_predictors.html
  
from sklearn.compose import make_column_selector
        
cat_cols = make_column_selector(dtype_include=object) (df)
print (cat_cols)
## or
num_selector = make_column_selector(dtype_include=np.number)
num_cols = num_selector (df)
print (num_cols)
```